# Optional Single-user Single-Signon Idea

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, serverfault, users, profile-page

I think it might be a good idea to allow users of Stack Overflow / meta - Stack Overflow / Server Fault etc to be able to use the same user ID profile data.  So for example, If I wanted to do so I could have signed into meta - Stack Overflow with my Stack Overflow User rather than having to create a completely identical user on meta-SO.

I realize this wouldn't be something everyone would want to do, but I think it should be an option for those who don't mind having the same user id / user data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already allow that. Use the same OpenID that you created for one of your other accounts. Then you'll be able to associate those accounts together and get a +100 rep bonus.